# ParseInt of toLocaleTimeString() in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, time, parseint

I have problem with parse string after toLocaleTimeString()

```
var b = new Date();
var c = b.toLocaleTimeString();
var d = c.split(":");
var e = parseInt(d[0]);
```

After this:
 Internet Explorer:
     e is NaN,
     d is "15"
 Chrome:
     e is 15,
     d is "15"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IE you need to use [**charAt()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) instead of `d[0]` after converting to string.

```js
var b = new Date();
var c = b.toLocaleTimeString();
var d = c.split(":");

// For IE Support...
var D = d.toString();
var e = parseInt(D.charAt(0));
if ( isNaN(e) === true ){
    var e = parseInt(D.charAt(1));
}

alert(d);
alert(e);
```